# Scope difficulties when adding methods to prototype

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype, factory

I'd like to create a factory that produces a function constructor as a product. The factory holds methods for adding methods to the products prototype. The instantiated product holds these functions for accessing the products doc field.

https://jsfiddle.net/84fzwvj7/2/

```
function Factory() {
    this.Product = function(doc = {}) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }
}

Factory.prototype.addDocField = function(name) {
    this.Product.prototype["set" + name] = function(value) {
        this.doc[name] = value;
    }
    this.Product.prototype["get" + name] = function() {
        return this.doc[name];
    }
    return this;
}

var MyClass = new Factory().addDocField("Test").Product;
var obj = new MyClass();
console.dir(obj.doc.Test);          // undefined
obj.setTest("Lorem Ipsum");
console.dir(obj.doc.Test);          // "Lorem Ipsum"
```

This method works fine for doc fields which need only getters / setters. But I need more complex field accessors like in this:

```
// ... Object was created before with an array like field
obj.users.create(login);
obj.users.deleteById("46891");
```

Sadly I can't figure out a way to define the `create` and `deleteById` functions and having their `this` keyword bound to `obj`. I tried adding the prototype methods to an object but that's where I can't figure out, how to get my scope right:

https://jsfiddle.net/5n5pachh/3/

```
Factory.prototype.addUserField = function(name) {
    this.Product.prototype[name] = {};

    // Using a classic function does not work because ...
    this.Product.prototype[name].create = function(login) {
        console.dir(this); // ... 'this' is bound to this.Product.prototype[name]
    }

    // Using an arrow function does not work because ...
    this.Product.prototype[name].create = function(login) {
        console.dir(this); // ... 'this' is bound to Factory.prototype.addUserField
    }

    // None of the above functions work how I want them to, because they can't
    // access the products doc field (i.e.: this.doc)

    return this;
}
```

(How) Is it possible to have the `create` and `deleteById` functions have their `this` keyword bound to my `obj` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the `this` scope onto your function. If I understand what you want `this` to represent this just means tagging `.bind(this.Product);`  onto the end of your functions:

```
this.Product.prototype[name].create = function(login) {
    console.dir(this); 
}.bind(this.Product);
```

But I dont think this entirely solves your problem - when you call `addUserField` there is not yet an instance of `Product` for you to bind to. So what you get with the above is `this` referencing the definition of `Product`, not your instance with a `doc`. For that you will need to refactor your code.

Here is a solution which changes your factory to actually create the instance of `Product`, not quite the same as yours but hopefully fulfils the same requirement

```js
function Factory() {
        
    this.createProduct = function(doc){
       var product = {doc:doc};
       userFields.forEach(function(uf){
           product[uf.name] = {};
           product[uf.name].create = uf.create.bind(product) ;
       })
       return product;
    }
    
    var userFields = [];
    this.addUserField = function(name){
      userFields.push({
           name: name,
           create: function(login){
              console.dir(this.doc); 
           }
       }) ;
       return this;
    }
}



// Use case
var obj = new Factory().addUserField("users").createProduct({foo:"bar"});
console.log(obj.doc)
obj.users.create();
```

Comment: Regarding "But I dont think this entirely solves your problem": Yes, I am currently testing that one aswell, since I found the same problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/5n5pachh/4/

Edit: Trying binding `this.Product.prototype` didn't make sense either.

Comment: @Fabi yep, we've followed the same trials - im currently just working on a refactor which loks exactly the same but works :)

Comment: @Fabi do you need this pattern of creating the class, and then `new`ing it? Or could your factory have a `createProduct(doc)` method? ie `var prod = new Factory().addUserField(...).createProduct(myDoc)`

Comment: I was just typing my comment to tell you that I'll try what you were implicitly trying, but then you posted just that. I'll try refactoring and come back to you. Guess that will work though. Thank you **very** much!